# Laravel Auth doesn't hash password

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

> These credentials do not match our records

This is laravel 5 error which is displayed when trying to log in. When I traced the request, to see my credentials, the password is displayed as a plain text.

I am using laravel auth, my LoginController code:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

protected $redirectTo = '/showMark';

protected $username = 'student_no';

public function __construct()
{
   // $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'getLogout']]);
}
  public function username()
{
return 'student_no';
}
```

User code:

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'accounts';
protected $primaryKey = 'student_no';
protected $fillable = [
     'student_no', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password'
];
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
$this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

So how can I fix this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: What about the database have you a hashed pass or not ?

Comment: @Maraboc yes they are hashed.

Comment: Ok can you add the code where you did the login ?

Comment: The user will transmit the password as "plain text". This is still secure if the transmission is done over HTTPS. The hashing will occur on the server before the password is stored in the database or verified against what's already in the database.

Comment: @Maraboc I've edited the post.

Comment: @apokryfos but when the app was on localhost, I could see the hashed pass.

Comment: You mean in the browser network tab you could see a hashed password?

Comment: No, I go through vendor files code, and dd(the attempts, requests, and credentials) then display the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when I dived into the code, there is function `password_verify($value, $hashedValue);` in BcryptHasher file that is responsible for validation of the credentials. it is PHP function which takes the plain password as a first argument and the stored password in your database as a second one.
Here was my problem. it exhausted me searching why it always returns false, my hashed passwords in database have been hashed by external webSite, and it looks hashed well. But no, the problem was in the passwords hashing.
It was for getting benefit,
Thank you